# How to assert torch.float32/64 using isinstance?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am writing a pipeline for my deep learning project, as a good practice, I try to do some assertions to make sure the data type matches, so it's easier to debug later! However, I do not know how to use `isinstance` to assert the `torch.Tensor's` `dtype`.

For example:

```
    assert isinstance(image, torch.Tensor) and isinstance(target['boxes'], torch.Tensor)
    assert isinstance(image.dtype, (torch.float32, torch.float64)) and isinstance(target['boxes'].dtype, (torch.float32, torch.float64))
```

Is using `assert image.dtype in [torch.float32, torch.float64]` the only method here? Is there an elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`torch.is_floating_point`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.is_floating_point.html)

```
assert torch.is_floating_point(image) and torch.is_floating_point(target['boxes'])
```

The function raises an exception if the input is not a tensor. Therefore it is not necessary to do an independent check for `torch.Tensor`.